# Finding out the email address my Stack Overflow account is linked to

Tags: support, user-accounts

I cannot remember which email address my Stack Overflow account is linked to. If I have my username, is there a way to easily find out which email address I used to log in to Stack Overflow?

Answer (score 7):

1. Go [here](https://stackexchange.com/users/971621/user994083)
2. Click `my logins`

[image]

3. Profit!

[image]

Comment: This assumes that the user can log in to the original account. Is there a way to access an account if I don't know the email address that was used to create it?

Comment: @user2269574: nope. if you have access to any openid login, you have access to your email address there.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is for those who can access their account but don't know which account is it; or which email the account is linked to?
1. Click your profile icon beside the Search label in any page inside stack overflow.
2. In the page that comes after, go to 'Edit Profile and Settings' in the area just below the search bar.
3. There you can see 'EMAIL SETTINGS'.
4. Go to the edit email for editing the linked email address and you can manage various settings of the account relating to email there.